# Trying to detect numbers in a conditional

Tags: python, string, console, numbers

I have an if statement that is checking a variable for any integers in the statement but I can't get it to work. This is what I have so far:

```
import re
c = input('input your numbers: ')
if(c == '1st ' + %d + ', 2nd ' + %d):
    n = re.findall('\d+', c)
    for i in n[:1]:
        print (i)  ##this prints the 1st number entered
    print (n[-1])  ##this prints the second number entered
```

Basically what I want is to be able to enter in a raw input of: '1st 10, 2nd 20' and then have those numbers printed to the console. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean this `if(c == '1st ' + %d + ', 2nd ' + %d):` ?

Comment: What errors are you seeing when you run your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this process  :

```
import re
c = input('input your numbers: ')
if('1st' not in c or '2nd' not in c):
    n = re.findall('\d+', c)
    for i in n[:1]:
        print (i)  ##this prints the 1st number entered
    print (n[-1])  ##this prints the second number entered
```

Comment: Hmm, inverted conditional? `if('1st' in c and '2nd' in c):` ?

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the original question. In his conditional he's looking for a specific structure to the input string. The conditional here is only checking that part of the input is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure I would implement it this way, but I'm just building off what you already have:

```
import re

def is_number(n):
  try:
    int(n)
  except ValueError:
    return False
  return True

def validate_token(token, prefix):
  tokens = token.split()
  if len(tokens) != 2:
    print ('{} does not contain a second entry'.format(token))
    return False
  if tokens[0] != prefix:
    print ('Entry is not in correct position: {0}. Was expecting {1}.'.format(token, prefix))
    return False
  return True

def read_input():
  first = '1st'
  second = '2nd'
  c = input('input your numbers: ')
  if (not (first in c and second in c)):
    print ('Please enter in format: 1st n1, 2nd n2')
    return

  tokens = c.split(',')
  if len(tokens) != 2:
    print ('Please separate entries 1st and 2nd by a ","')
    return

  if (not validate_token(tokens[0], first) or not validate_token(tokens[1], second)):
    print ('Not a valid entry invalid...')
    return

  n1 = tokens[0].split()[1]
  n2 = tokens[1].split()[1]

  if (not is_number(n1)):
    print('n1 is not a number!')
    return

  if (not is_number(n2)):
    print('n2 is not a number!')
    return

  n = re.findall(r'\d+', c)
  for i in n[:1]:
    print (i)  ##this prints the 1st number entered
  print (n[-1])  ##this prints the second number entered

read_input()
```

Yes single slash works. Apologies. Updated code in link and above. Please note that most of the effort above is validating the correct input. If someone has something more succinct please share.

Let's explain the validations done here:

1. Check that the input string contains 1st and 2nd
2. Check that the input string has the correct length
3. Check that the input string's individual tokens are correct
   a. First check they are the correct length
   b. Check that they are in the correct order
4. Check that the final element we wish to extract is in fact a number.

Tested here: https://repl.it/Jooi/8

Comment: Did you try it with single slash ?

Comment: `\d` is a digit (a character in the range 0-9), and `+` means 1 or more times. So, `\d+` is 1 or more digits. So , `\d+` works well. :)

Comment: @ksai updated code thanks. I did try it with a single slash, and I believe my original bug was elsewhere.